# Add UNIX timestamp to start/end of webcam recording

Tags: python, opencv, unix, timestamp

I am using OpenCV in Python to record data from a webcam. The videos are recorded for a fixed number of frames so they all have the same length. I would like to get the exact UNIX timestamp for the start and end of the recording.

Below is my code for an example video of 5s (30 fps, so 150 frames in total).

```
import cv2
import time 

video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#define frame height and width 
frame_width0 = int(video_capture_0.get(3))
frame_height0 = int(video_capture_0.get(4))

# create output file
out0 = cv2.VideoWriter('test.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(str('X'),str('V'),str('I'),str('D')), 30.0, (frame_width0,frame_height0))


counter = 0

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    counter += 1
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()


    if (ret0):
        #write video
        out0.write(frame0)
        # show video
        cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)


    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')) or counter == 150: 
        end_time = time.time()
        break


# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture_0.release()
out0.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # closes all frames

time_passed = end_time - start_time

print('Start time : ', start_time, '\n')
print('End time : ', end_time, '\n')
print('Time passed : ', time_passed, '\n')
```

Implementing the time.time() component however always gives me a delay of roughly 0.23s.

```
Start time :  1574694237.1550183 

End time :  1574694242.387653 

Time passed :  5.232634782791138
```

Does anybody know why this is and how I could improve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-run the code `ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()` before `start_time = time.time()` to activate the camera, and <s>commit</s> comment the `cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)` and `(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'))`, then the result will be very closed to 5.0

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "commit"?

Comment: @Jana_K My typo, commit -> comment